# OMAP SPI controller

Tags: arm, spi, omap

Does anyone ever develop some application to control the spi device on OMAP3? I can load the spi driver "mcspi", but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I haven't used that chip specifically, but have a lot of SPI experience. Could you narrow down the question a bit?

Comment: Isn't information about platform missing, here? I would guess Linux from the driver name, but it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So first I need to apologize for my previous shoot from the hip answer.

I too have now started looking into trying to get the McSPI's working and it has been some what painful.  TI does not have lot of documentation, and I still haven;t been successful in getting any of the McSPI's to actually work, yet.  But I thought I would post a link to the beagle board google discussion on the subject, as it appears they have been successful at getting at least McSPI3 working on the OMAP3530.

http://groups.google.com/group/beagleboard/browse_thread/thread/15d9488c1ec314ef/5ca06c67ff438106?q=mcspi3#5ca06c67ff438106

Answer (score 0):

As of at least **PSP 3.00.00.04**, the mcspi driver is integrated with the Linux spi stack.

Turn on

> CONFIG_SPI and CONFIG_SPI_OMAP24XX

in your kernel.

[Here's how to use spi devices, in general.](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/spi/spi-summary)

There is also the spidev driver, which presents a char device to userspace, but it's experimental.